# PyGame KEYDOWN event not captured

Tags: python, linux, events, pygame, keydown

When I execute the following code, the KEYDOWN events are not captured.  The desired result is to exit the loop on any key press.  How can I make the code have the desired effect?

```
while slideshow:

    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: slideshow = False

    scope.screen.blit(safimg, (0, 0))

    for t in statsurfs:
        scope.screen.blit(t, (fontline * lnum, fontcol))
        lnum += 1

    lnum = 5

    for t in dynsurfs:
        scope.screen.blit(t, (fontline * lnum, fontcol * 2 - t.get_width()))
        lnum += 1

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.time.delay(wtime * 1000)

    for i in imgfiles:
        img = pygame.image.load(i).convert()
        #img = pygame.transform.scale(img, scope.size)
        scope.screen.blit(img,(0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(wtime * 1000)
```

Also, any tips on how to optimize the code would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to Python programming.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely with the way you keep the program from going too fast (aka the clock).  You're currently using

```
pygame.time.delay(1000 * wtime)
```

which doesn't work as you intend.

The correct way to do this is by using

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

(set clock at the beginning of your code) and then calling

```
clock.tick(FPS)
```

at the end of your loop (where FPS is the desired frames per second).  This will make the program run through the loop 60 times a second.  In your code,

```
pygame.time.delay(1000 * wtime)
```

simply makes the program wait, but the program isn't actually running anything; it's just waiting.  If you have other questions just reply to this answer.  Good luck :D